# Razor - C# Syntax for iis

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have ASP.NET Razor - C# syntax like this

```
<tbody>
  @foreach (var item in Model.item)
  {
     if (item.TYPE == "R")
     {
        foreach (var detail in Model.Rareitemdetail)
        {
           <tr>
               <td>@detail.SEQUENCENO</td>
               <td>@detail.NAME</td>
               <td>@detail.DESC</td>
               <td>@detail.QTY</td>
          </tr>
        }
     }
     else
     {
        foreach (var detail in Model.commonitemdetail)
        {
           <tr>
               <td>@detail.SEQUENCENO</td>
               <td>@detail.NAME</td>
               <td>@detail.DESC</td>
               <td>@detail.QTY</td>
          </tr>
        }
     }
  }
</tbody>
```

When I run on Visual Studio `if` and `else` it's working, after I deploy to IIS for `else` it's normal but for `if` it says "An error occurred while processing your request.". how to type the syntax?

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to find the actual error message. Do you have any logging for your application? You might be able to find something in Event Viewer. You can also try setting the environment variable `aspnetcore_environment` to `Development` in IIS.

Comment: It's not easy to get an answer with the details you provided, most probably the Model.Rareitemdetail would be null and causing an null reference exception internally.

Comment: This error is not detailed. We cannot get useful information from this error message. I suggest you use FRT to get detailed error messages: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis